# Create a descendant of a existing ComponentEditor (TFDQuery)

Tags: delphi, components, firedac

I try to write a new ComponentEditor in Delphi V10, this should add a new menuitem to the component TFDQuery when you made a right-click to the component at the formdesigner.

[Shows you the original ComponentEditor of TFDQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTLdy.jpg)

I have severeal problems with my code. Sometimes the correct menu are appears sometime not. My new menuitem is working correct, but the descendant four menuitems of the old component editor are fires a exception sometimes not. After restart the IDE, my component are not registered anymore.

with google i didn't find specified information for my problem

May somebody can give me a hint, what im doing wrong.

Best Regards
Gregor

follow my code

```
UNIT GK_Query_Reg;

INTERFACE

USES
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, dbReg, DsDesign,
  ToolsAPI, DesignIntf, DesignEditors, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.Stan.Error,
  FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Async, FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

TYPE
  TgkQueryEditor = CLASS(TComponentEditor)
  PRIVATE
    FOldEditor: IComponentEditor;
  PROTECTED
  PUBLIC
    CONSTRUCTOR Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner); OVERRIDE;
    DESTRUCTOR Destroy; OVERRIDE;
    PROCEDURE ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); OVERRIDE;
    FUNCTION GetVerb(Index: Integer): STRING; OVERRIDE;
    FUNCTION GetVerbCount: Integer; OVERRIDE;
    PROCEDURE Edit; OVERRIDE;
    PROCEDURE Copy; OVERRIDE;
    PROCEDURE ShowEditor;
END;

PROCEDURE Register;

IMPLEMENTATION

VAR
  ComponentEditor: IComponentEditor;

CONSTRUCTOR TgkQueryEditor.Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner);
BEGIN
  INHERITED Create(AComponent, ADesigner);
  FOldEditor := ComponentEditor;
  OutputDebugString(Pchar(Format('Create Component %d',[FOldEditor.GetVerbCount])));
END;

DESTRUCTOR TgkQueryEditor.Destroy;
BEGIN
  INHERITED;
  OutputDebugString(Pchar('Destroy Component'));
END;

PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
VAR
  I: Integer;
BEGIN
  I := INDEX - FOldEditor.GetVerbCount;
  OutputDebugString(Pchar(Format('ExecuteVerb: %d, %d' ,[i,index])));
  CASE I OF
    0:
      ShowEditor;
    ELSE
      FOldEditor.ExecuteVerb(INDEX)
  END;
END;

FUNCTION TgkQueryEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): STRING;
VAR
  I: Integer;
BEGIN
  I := INDEX - FOldEditor.GetVerbCount;
  OutputDebugString(Pchar(Format('GetVerb: %d, %d' ,[i,index])));
  CASE I OF
    0:
      Result := '&Show Form...';
    ELSE
      Result := FOldEditor.GetVerb(INDEX)
  END;
END;

FUNCTION TgkQueryEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
BEGIN
  OutputDebugString(Pchar(Format('GetVerbCount old: %d' ,[FOldEditor.GetVerbCount])));
  Result := FOldEditor.GetVerbCount + 1;
  OutputDebugString(Pchar(Format('GetVerbCount: %d' ,[result])));
END;

PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.Edit;
BEGIN
  OutputDebugString(Pchar('Edit Component'));
  FOldEditor.Edit;
END;

PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.Copy;
BEGIN
  OutputDebugString(PChar('Copy Component'));
  FOldEditor.Copy;
END;

PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.ShowEditor;
VAR
  AQuery: TFDQuery;
BEGIN
  AQuery := TFDQuery(Component);
  IF (AQuery.Connection = NIL) THEN BEGIN
    ShowMessage('Assign Database first.');
    exit;
  END;
  IF (AQuery <> NIL) THEN BEGIN
    ShowMessage('OK for Open Query-Builder!');
  END;
END;

PROCEDURE Register;
VAR
  FDQ: TFDQuery;
BEGIN
  FDQ := TFDQuery.Create(NIL);
  TRY
    ComponentEditor := GetComponentEditor(FDQ, NIL);
    OutputDebugString(pChar(Format('Register Component %s, %d',[ComponentEditor.GetComponent.ClassName,ComponentEditor.GetVerbCount])));
  FINALLY
    FreeAndNIL(FDQ);
  END;
  RegisterComponentEditor(TFDQuery, TgkQueryEditor);
END;

END.
```

Comment: My first thought is that the `ComponentEditor` variable isn't needed. Just call the inherited routines with `inherited`, the same as you would do within any other descendant class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution

```
UNIT GK_Query_Reg;

INTERFACE

  USES
    Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms,
    Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Menus, dbReg, DsDesign,
    ToolsAPI, DesignIntf, DesignEditors, FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option,
    FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.Stan.Error,
    FireDAC.DatS, FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
    FireDAC.DApt, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client;

  TYPE
    TgkQueryEditor = CLASS(TComponentEditor)
    PRIVATE
      FOldEditor: TComponentEditor;
    PROTECTED
    PUBLIC
      CONSTRUCTOR Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner); OVERRIDE;
      DESTRUCTOR Destroy; OVERRIDE;
      PROCEDURE ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer); OVERRIDE;
      FUNCTION GetVerb(Index: Integer): STRING; OVERRIDE;
      FUNCTION GetVerbCount: Integer; OVERRIDE;
      PROCEDURE Edit; OVERRIDE;
      PROCEDURE Copy; OVERRIDE;
      PROCEDURE ShowEditor;
    END;

  PROCEDURE Register;

IMPLEMENTATION

  VAR
    PrevEditorClass: TComponentEditorClass = NIL;

  CONSTRUCTOR TgkQueryEditor.Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner);
  BEGIN
    INHERITED Create(AComponent, ADesigner);
    IF Assigned(PrevEditorClass) THEN BEGIN
      FOldEditor := TComponentEditor(PrevEditorClass.Create(AComponent, ADesigner));
    END;
  END;

  DESTRUCTOR TgkQueryEditor.Destroy;
  BEGIN
    INHERITED;
  END;

  PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
  BEGIN
    IF (INDEX = 0) THEN BEGIN
      ShowEditor
    END ELSE BEGIN
      IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN BEGIN
        FOldEditor.ExecuteVerb(INDEX - 1);
      END;
    END;
  END;

  FUNCTION TgkQueryEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): STRING;
  BEGIN
    IF (INDEX = 0) THEN BEGIN
      Result := '&Show Form...'
    END ELSE BEGIN
      IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN BEGIN
        Result := FOldEditor.GetVerb(INDEX - 1);
      END;
    END;
  END;

  FUNCTION TgkQueryEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
  BEGIN
    Result := 1;
    IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN BEGIN
      Inc(Result, FOldEditor.GetVerbCount);
    END;
  END;

  PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.Edit;
  BEGIN
//    IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN BEGIN
//      FOldEditor.Edit;
//    END;
    ShowEditor;
  END;

  PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.Copy;
  BEGIN
    IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN BEGIN
      FOldEditor.Copy;
    END;
  END;

  PROCEDURE TgkQueryEditor.ShowEditor;
  VAR
    AQuery: TFDQuery;
  BEGIN
    AQuery := Component AS TFDQuery;
    IF Assigned(AQuery) THEN BEGIN
      IF NOT Assigned(AQuery.Connection) THEN BEGIN
        ShowMessage('Assign Database first.');
      END ELSE BEGIN
        ShowMessage('OK for open a form to change SQL-Code!');
        Designer.Modified;
      END;
    END ELSE BEGIN
      ShowMessage('Component not assigned!')
    END;
  END;



  PROCEDURE Register;
  VAR
    FDQ: TFDQuery;
    Editor: IComponentEditor;
  BEGIN
    FDQ := TFDQuery.Create(NIL);
    TRY
      Editor := GetComponentEditor(FDQ, NIL);
      IF Assigned(Editor) THEN BEGIN
        PrevEditorClass := TComponentEditorClass((Editor AS TObject).ClassType);
      END;
    FINALLY
      Editor := NIL;
      FDQ.Free;
    END;
    RegisterComponentEditor(TFDQuery, TgkQueryEditor);
  END;

END.
```