# Can I add a second component editor to a component in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, localization, firemonkey

Delphi IDE has a component editor for TLang component (Language Designer)
I wrote a custom component editor to TLang, to help with localization tasks. 
I registered it in a design time package.

```
  RegisterComponentEditor(TLang, TMyLangComponentEditor);
```

This works. Now when I dbl-click the component, I get my flashy component editor. But it hides the original TLang editor. 
How can I have access to both editors in the right-click menu ?

ex: In my component editor I have:

```
function TMyLangComponentEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result := '&Show IDE Lang Designer';
    1: Result := '&Show My Lang Editor';
  else
    raise ENotImplemented.Create('verb not supported');
  end;
end;

procedure TMyLangComponentEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: ;                //  <---  what goes here to open the IDE Language designer ?
    1: ShowMyLangForm;
  else
    raise ENotImplemented.Create('verb not supported.');
  end;
end;
```

I'm afraid that, by registering a new component editor, the old one got lost...

Comment: I notice you have the same accelerator ('&S') for both the existing editor and your one.  Have you tried using different ones?

Comment: You are correct.   But my question concerns to ExecuteVerb  Index 0. How to call the original component editor

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are asking, I was just curious, that's all, in case with a different accelerator the existing editor could be invoked without your code having to deal with it.

Comment: Multiple component editors cannot be registered for the same class.  A newer registration replaces an older registration.  To get the behavior you are looking for, you would have to derive your editor from the standard `TLang` editor, which AFAIK is not a public type you can use directly. So, unless there is a public design-time function to invoke the standard editor, you are likely SOL (ie, like there is `ColnEdit.ShowCollectionEditor()` to invoke a standard `TCollection` editor).

Comment: Unit DesignEditors exposes function GetComponentEditor, which returns the IComponentEditor interface of the component editor registered for the given component. Perhaps you can get that interface and retrieve the implementing class from it before registering your own component editor.

Comment: That worked for me Uwe Raabe. Thanks. See details in the answer below

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation I found this:

[Create a descendant of a existing ComponentEditor (TFDQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547929/create-a-descendant-of-a-existing-componenteditor-tfdquery)

This worked for me. But I had to adapt the code because IDE TLang  component editor implements no verbs, so calling ExecuteVerb(0) does not work. But It does implement the Edit method.

Thanks Uwe Raabe for pointing the solution

Here is the code:

```
unit LangToolEditor; // LangTool alternative TLang component editor

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,System.UITypes,System.Classes,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.Types,     // TLang
  DesignEditors,
  DesignIntf;

type
  TLangToolComponentEditor = class(TComponentEditor)
  private
    fOldEditor: TComponentEditor;
    procedure ShowLangToolForm;
  public
    constructor Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner); override;
    destructor  Destroy;                                              override;
    function  GetVerbCount: Integer;            override;
    function  GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;  override;
    procedure ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);      override;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation  //---------------------------------

uses
  fTLangTool; //  TFormTLangTool  - LangTool editor form

// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33547929/create-a-descendant-of-a-existing-componenteditor-tfdquery
VAR
  PrevEditorClass:TComponentEditorClass=NIL;   //save class of original IDE TLang Editor

constructor TLangToolComponentEditor.Create(AComponent: TComponent; ADesigner: IDesigner);
begin
  inherited Create(AComponent, ADesigner);

  IF Assigned(PrevEditorClass) THEN BEGIN  //must be
    fOldEditor := TComponentEditor(PrevEditorClass.Create(AComponent, ADesigner));
  END;
end;

destructor TLangToolComponentEditor.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TLangToolComponentEditor.GetVerbCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 2;
end;

function TLangToolComponentEditor.GetVerb(Index: Integer): string;
begin
  case Index of
    0: Result := 'Show &LangTool Editor..';
    1: IF Assigned(fOldEditor) THEN Result := 'Show IDE Lang Designer..'
         else Result := 'Old editor not found';
  end;
end;

procedure TLangToolComponentEditor.ExecuteVerb(Index: Integer);
begin
  case Index of
    0: ShowLangToolForm;
    1: IF Assigned(FOldEditor) THEN FOldEditor.Edit
       else MessageDlg('Old editor not found', TMsgDlgType.mtInformation,
         [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOk], 0);
  end;
end;

procedure AssignTLang(aLangSrc,aLangDest:TLang);  // TLang --> TLang    same as aLangDest.Assign(aLangSrc)
var i:integer; aLang:String; aStrs1,aStrs2:TStrings;
begin
  aLangDest.Lang := aLangSrc.Lang;  //original
  aLangDest.Original.Assign(aLangSrc.Original); //ok
  // TODO: dispose Resources?
  aLangDest.Resources.Clear;
  for i:= 0 to aLangSrc.Resources.Count-1 do
    begin
      aLang  := aLangSrc.Resources.Strings[i];
      aStrs1 := TStrings(aLangSrc.Resources.Objects[i]);
      aLangDest.AddLang(aLang);
      aStrs2 := aLangDest.LangStr[aLang];  //get access to strings
      aStrs2.Assign(aStrs1);              //copy strings
    end;
end;

procedure TLangToolComponentEditor.ShowLangToolForm;
var  DesignerForm: TFormTLangTool; aLangSrc,aLangDest:TLang;
begin
  DesignerForm := TFormTLangTool.Create(nil);
  try
    // Set curent value to designer form
    aLangSrc  := (Component as TLang);
    aLangDest := DesignerForm.Lang1;
    AssignTLang(aLangSrc,aLangDest);         // Componemnt --> LangTool.Lang1
    DesignerForm.populateGridWithLanguages;  // Lang1 --> grid
    // Show ModalForm, and then take result
    if DesignerForm.ShowModal = mrOK then     // modal
      begin
        DesignerForm.copyGridToLang1;
        aLangSrc := DesignerForm.Lang1;
        aLangDest:= (Component as TLang);
        AssignTLang(aLangSrc,aLangDest);         // as in aLangDest.Assign( aLangSrc );
      end;
    Designer.Modified;
  finally
    DesignerForm.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure Register;
VAR
  aLang: TLang;
  Editor: IComponentEditor;
BEGIN
  aLang := TLang.Create(NIL);
  TRY
    Editor := GetComponentEditor(aLang, NIL);
    IF Assigned(Editor) THEN BEGIN
      PrevEditorClass := TComponentEditorClass((Editor AS TObject).ClassType);
    END;
  FINALLY
    Editor := NIL;
    aLang.Free;
  END;
  RegisterComponentEditor(TLang, TLangToolComponentEditor);
END;

end.
```

Comment: Complete code for LangTool can be found @ https://github.com/omarreis/LangTool